# Why Did J.R.R. Tolkien Capitalize Certain Words Throughout His Books?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

**Why did J.R.R. Tolkien randomly capitalize various words throughout his books?**

My husband asked me this question today and we were wondering if there's any rhyme or reason to Tolkien's capitalization process. These are examples taken from the *LOTR* trilogy and *The Hobbit*:

- *And there upon that hill they looked east to the **Shadow** and west to the **Twilight**, and they plighted their troth and were glad.* (ROTK)
- *She shall not be the bridge of any **Man** less than the King of both Gondor and Arnor. To me then even our victory can bring only sorrow or parting -- but to you hope of joy for a while. Alas, my son! I fear that to Arwen the **Doom of Man** may seem hard at the ending.* (ROTK)
- *In the **Wide World** the Wood-elves lingered in the twilight of our **Sun and Moon**, but loved best the stars; and they wandered in the great forests that grew tall in lands that are now lost.* (THE HOBBIT)
- *It is fortunate that I could find it, for it is a healing plant that the **Men of the West** brought to Middle-earth. Athelas, they named it, and it grows now sparsely and only  near places where they dwelt or camped of old; and it is not known in the **North**, except to some of those who wander in the **Wild**.* (FOTR)
- *"Nob, you woolly-pated ninny! he cried. "Can't you give old friends their names? You shouldn't go scaring me like that, with times as they are. Well, well! And where have you come from? I never expected to see any of you folk, and that's a fact: going off into the **Wild** with that Strider, and all those **Black Men** about."* (ROTK)
- *Yet hardy and full of wrath as he was, it is said that when he camed down from the **Gate** he looked grey in the face, as one who has felt great fear.* (ROTK)

Are these kind of examples style choices? Did Tolkien give careful consideration to each word he used and how? Because I know Tolkien also developed his own Elvish languages, I wondered if perhaps he applied some of the rules from his Elvish languages to the way he wrote English. I feel confident in saying that I don't believe the random capitalizations are mistakes. And some of the words capitalized make total sense:

- the One Ring, the Eye
- the Nazgûl, the Mumakil
- Théoden, Éowyn, Éomer
- the Orcs, the Haradrim, the Elves, the Dúnedain, the Hobbits

Although "elves" and "hobbits" are not always capitalized in Tolkien's writing (This makes sense, as we don't capitalized "people" or "humans"; however, we do capitalize "American" or "British".).

**Why did J.R.R. Tolkien randomly capitalize words?**

<sub>I'm not asking this in English.se because I felt with the special languages associated with the *Lord of the Rings* trilogy, plus the existence of *The Silmarillion* (which I do not have access to), the answer might more easily be found at SFF.se.</sub>

Comment: It's a code! Let's decipher it before someone else finds the hidden treasure!

Comment: Sometimes this has to do with poetic structure, beginning of stanzas instead of sentences. Doesn't seem to be the case with your examples though.

Comment: Tolkien was primarily a linguist, with credits including working on the Oxford English Dictionary, and a professorship at Leeds University's Languages department. I'm not sure why he capitalized words the way he did, but I'm certain he had a reason. :)

Comment: I understand your motivation for putting the question, but I see it better place in English.Se as it may just come down to an English thing.

Comment: Incidentally, this type of thing can be seen in the English used by the Founding Fathers in America, though that predates Tolkien by a few hundred years. "That whenever any Form of Government becomes destructive of these ends, it is the Right of the People to alter or to abolish it, and to institute new Government, laying its foundation on such principles and organizing its powers in such form, as to them shall seem most likely to effect their Safety and Happiness."

Comment: 'Man', 'Men of the West' and 'Black Men' are peoples, just like Orcs, Haradrim, Elves, Dúnedain. The Wild, the North and the Gate are specific places. That could possibly be said of the Wide World, Shadow and Twilight too. The Sun and Moon are the names of our sun and moon. That just leaves the Doom of Man, which I think can be compared to Armageddon or the Apocalypse.

Comment: @GabeWillard: No, I don't think it's like that. That's just capitalizing every Noun that you think needs some extra Emphasis. Tolkien was more selective than that.

Comment: Also keep in mind that "North" referring to a location is always capitalized in proper modern English.

Comment: Short answer:  for emphasis and to make it clear that the subject is "THE ______" rather than "a ______".  Saying "Men" is different from saying "men".  The former refers to humans, the latter to male human adults.  Another common example is "the enemy" vs. "the Enemy";  the former refers to those who oppose U.S., the latter refers to the source of all opposition to everything we stand for, i.e., Sauron.

Comment: @GabeWillard I know it's an old question, but I wanna nit pick at "predates Tolkien by a few hundred years", the last Founding Father to die was Madison, in the year 1836, Tolkien was born 101 years later. A hundred years isn't all that much in terms of linguistics and Tolkien was very much about history and origin stories, so the language usage of the Founding Fathers may very well have influenced him (as you said).

Answer (score 109, accepted):

These aren't random capitalizations: Tolkien is capitalizing words that refer to proper nouns or concepts that would unceremoniously get capitalization if expressed directly.

- **Shadow:** the personification of Sauron. As described by Anita Miller Bell in [*"The Lord of the Rings" and the Emerging Generation: A Study of the Message and Medium. J. R. R. Tolkien and Peter Jackson*](http://gradworks.umi.com/33/64/3364843.html):

  > [L]et us consider Tolkien's use of the simple of image of shadow to explore the realities of evil. Tolkien often uses simple, everyday images to consider complex and at times paradoxical realities in life. [...] In *LOTR*, Tolkien often gives substance to the insubstantial reality of shadow by the simple capitalization of "S"; shadow becomes Shadow, the absence of light becomes the personification of Sauron.
- **Twilight:** refers to the Undying Lands/Aman/Lands of the West, which were bathed in perpetual twilight.
- **Man:** Mankind. As described by Tolkien in the postscript to a letter to C. A. Furth (so-called [Letter 20](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Letter_20)):

  > *Men* with a capital is, I think, used in text when 'human kind' are specifically intended; and *man*, *men* with a minuscule are occasionally and loosely used as 'adult male' and 'people'.
- **Doom of Man:** This refers to the "gift" Men were given by Eru: [mortality](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/d/doomofmen.html) (doom in this sense is "fate").
- **Wide World:** Arda as a whole.
- **Sun** / **Moon:** we capitalize these in colloquial English as well, but in Tolkien's Legendarium, the Sun and Moon [were also maiar](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/s/sun.html).
- **Men of the West** / **Black Men:** correctly capitalized, just as you would capitalize "European". They are, in effect, ethnic groups of Men.
- **North:** Refers to Arnor, the northern frontier of the realm of Man in Middle-earth.
- **Wild:** Refers to, well, the untamed parts of Middle-earth. It's the proper name people gave to those parts, like in the US with [Unorganized Territory](http://www.maine.gov/revenue/propertytax/unorganizedterritory/unorganized.htm).
- **Gate:** Refers to the Gate of Moria, which was a Dwarven landmark about as important, if not moreso, than the *Statue* of Liberty or the Gateway *Arch*.

Comment: +1 Much more encompassing than my answer. I would suggest however that in the particular example that the OP gives (from The Return of the King) that "Gate" refers to the *Black Gate*, and not the Gate of Moria.

Comment: @NominSim I thought that at first too, but I located the reference and it's actually from the appendices where Tolkien describes the war between Dwarves and Orcs in Moria, at the end of the third section within Appendix A Part III: Durin's Folk.

Comment: It could be the Gate of Minas Tirith. I could not find the quote in the OP with a quick text scan to confirm that, though. Alas. I didn't scan the appendices.

Comment: @MarkTrapp My apologies then, I just assumed from it being ROTK and "coming down from [it]...with great fear".

Comment: Thank you for a really great answer. I *suspected* the issue was one of proper nouns, but then I got stuck on "Sun", "Moon", and "Gate". Just to give you a background, I'm currently reading the trilogy and *The Hobbit*. I've made it partially through ROTK and haven't touched *The Hobbit*. I've seen the movies a lot, but those obviously aren't canon. So your help is appreciated. Thanks again! :)

Comment: ELU note: "Sun" and "moon" (and "earth") are actually not often capitalized in English, except when other astronomical bodies are also mentioned. Hence "The sun rose while the moon was still in the sky" vs. "Mercury and Venus are located between the Sun and Earth."

Comment: @trlkly Some prominent modern style guides tell us not to capitalise them but this was hardly standard practice through the ages.

Comment: I would also have mentioned that there is also often a feeling that were the word not capitalised it would have a different, less specific sense.

Comment: Can a person be personified?  The word _metonym_ might be useful here.

Answer (score 13):

Sometimes Tolkien used capitalization to add weight of emphasis to objects or places, either as an indirect reference to the proper noun (such as referring to Mount Doom as the Mountain), or as a personification of some greater concept.

He did not use capitalization consistently, so it is fair to assume that much of it depends upon the immediate context of the statement.  For example, in the 50th Anniversary Edition, it was noted in the [Addenda and Corrigenda](http://www.hammondandscull.com/addenda/rings.html) that Gondor was titled “**C**ity of the **K**ings” on page 973, but then was called “city of the kings” on page 1062, suggesting that Tolkien chose, in the first instance, to capitalize ‘City’ as a means of denoting special import or majesty to the name.

Most of the races received capitalization when named, but again, this was somewhat inconsistent on Tolkien’s part (“hobbit”, in particular, often went uncapitalized).  However, this does explain “Man” and “Black Men” in the quotes provided.

“Wild”, “North”, “Twilight” and “Shadow” all referred to specific geographic regions (“Shadow” can refer to either Sauron himself, or the lands directly under his control), and the capitalizations indicate that they are being used as if they were proper nouns (although this appears to be some poetic license).

“Sun” and “Moon” refer to the personifications of celestial bodies (maia, as Mark Trapp points out).

“Doom of Man” is the [title given to Man’s mortality](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/d/doomofmen.html).

The Gate reference is the shortened form of the proper name for the specific gate in question.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer! +1 It certainly makes sense, what you and **Mark Trapp** have said. For some of the words I *could* tell it was a proper noun, but, yes, like "Gate", "Wild", "Sun", and "Moon", were confusing to me. Also, thanks for assuming I'm intelligent enough to not need the concept of a proper noun explained to me. Most appreciated! :)