# Why does Gandalf show such reverence for Galadriel and Elrond?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, the-hobbit, the-silmarillion, maiar

Particularly in the Hobbit movies, Elrond mentions that Gandalf answers to Galadriel. Though Gandalf is a Maiar, one of Ainur, shouldn't he be regarded as one of the elders one above the Noldor?

Comment: Good question.  Are you asking about the movies alone, or would answers based primarily (or exclusively) on the books be acceptable?  Note that if you don't say "The books don't count", the answer will likely be "Peter Jackson ruins everything", or some variation there of.

Comment: Related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46411/who-in-middle-earth-knows-the-istaris-origin/46449#46449

Comment: Also, this makes me wonder how and by whom the Istari got turned into "wizards" (in-universe). Trying to find out if that's been asked before here.

Comment: I think its Gandalf's personal preference. Elrond and Galadriel are Elven royalty. Gandalf's entire premise is to be as low-key and humble as possible. He is also incredibly pure, which is why he hold a lot of regard for these, *Lords*. I believe he also holds a similar regard for the likes of Thorin and Aragorn.

Comment: Rather than "reverence" it is "deference." He is not meant to meddle, only to aide.

Comment: @CodeMed I know it's how I answer to my spouse. *shifty eyes*

Comment: @AdamDavis somehow I read that as "he is only meant to meddle, not to aide." and thought nothing of it, heh...

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### Canon

One of the opening paragraphs of "The Istari", an essay printed in *Unfinished Tales*, largely answers this (emphasis mine):

> [The Wizards] came from over the Sea out of the Uttermost West; though **this was for long known only to Círdan, Guardian of the Third Ring, master of the Grey Havens**, who saw their landings upon the western shores. Emissaries they were from Lords of the West, the Valar, who still took counsel for the governance of Middle-earth, and when the shadow of Sauron began first to stir again took this means of resisting him. For with the consent of Eru they sent members of their own high order, but clad in bodies of as of Men, real and not feigned, but subject to the fears and pains and weariness of earth, able to hunger and thirst and be slain; though because of their noble spirits they did not die, and aged only by the cares and labours of many long years. And this the Valar did, desiring to amend the errors of old, especially that they had attempted to guard and seclude the Eldar by their own might and glory fully revealed; whereas **now their emissaries were forbidden to reveal themselves in forms of majesty, or to seek to rule the wills of Men and Elves by open display of power, but coming in shapes weak and humble were bidden to advise and persuade Men and Elves to good**, and to seek to unite in love and understanding all those whom Sauron, should he come again, would endeavour to dominate and corrupt.
>
> <sup><sub>*Unfinished Tales* Part 4 Chapter II: "The Istari"</sub></sup>

From the above paragraph, the answer has two related parts:

- The Elves don't defer more to Gandalf because they don't know what he actually is. It's not entirely clear what the Elves *do* think Gandalf is, but it seems safe to say that they would be more deferent if they knew he was one of their Angelic spirits.
- Gandalf is forbidden from setting himself above them. This is Saruman's great failing, incidentally: the Wizards are meant to be teachers and counsellors only, not rulers. So from that perspective, it's *not* true that Gandalf is higher than the Noldor; he may be of a higher order of being, but within Middle-earth he's merely an advisor

### Jacksonverse

Now that the real stuff is out of the way, let's move on to the films. The specific exchange from *An Unexpected Journey* is:

> **Gandalf:** With or without our help, these dwarves will march on the mountain. They are determined to reclaim their homeland. I do not believe Thorin Oakenshield feels that he’s answerable to anyone. Nor for that matter am I.
>
> **Elrond:** It is not me you must answer to.
>
> *[Galadriel turns around]*
>
> **Gandalf:** Lady Galadriel.
>
> <sup><sub>*The Hobbit: An Unexpected Journey* (2013)</sub></sup>

There is, of course, no sensible reason why Gandalf should have to answer to Galadriel alone; although he doesn't command her, equally *she* doesn't command *him*.

Unfortunately I don't believe an official script has been made available, so there isn't likely to be a canon explanation of Jackson's intentions here. However, the most sensible explanation is that Elrond is referring not to Galadriel, but to the White Council.

[I discuss the nature of the White Council elsewhere on this site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91933/who-does-tolkien-include-in-the-category-the-wise), but the gist is that they are a loosely-affiliated group of powerful beings (including Gandalf, Saruman, Elrond, and Galadriel) who coordinate their efforts to counter the advances of Sauron. This is the one group in Middle-earth for whom it might be sensible to say that Gandalf "answers to."

My interpretation, then, is that Elrond's line and the subsequent appearance of Galadriel
isn't meant to convey "Gandalf answers to Galadriel", but rather that Galadriel's presence changes the nature of the conversation; rather than a discussion between disagreeing friends (Gandalf and Elrond), it has turned into a meeting of the White Council, and it's to *them* that Gandalf must answer.

Comment: Incidentally, this is my 100th answer in the [tag:lord-of-the-rings] tag. [*phweeeeet*](https://youtu.be/ApbvchiEdTY?t=1m59s)

Comment: Although I have always suspected that the Elves are clever/perceptive enough to know that Gandalf is something greater than themselves, despite not knowing exactly what he is, this is another brilliant answer.  The second part of your summary is close to what I was going to say - Gandalf's success is largely a reflection of his humility, a virtue that Tolkien held in especially high esteem.  He wouldn't allow himself to be treated as anything more than a wise, helpful old coot.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I found the area in the script. In an unexpected journey after Gandalf speaks to Elrond and Elrond questions Gandalf about his quest. The first meeting of the White Council and Gandalf presents the Morgul Blade. http://youtu.be/WDrHFsX6FsE

Comment: @user3695782 Thanks for that; I've updated my answer to discuss it

Comment: @WadCheber [It's been said before](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/46411/who-in-middle-earth-knows-the-istaris-origin) that Elrond and Galadriel knew *where* Gandalf came from, if not exactly what he was; that makes me curious what they thought he was, although I don't think Tolkien has an answer

Comment: @JasonBaker - Actually, this raises the question of how Galadriel managed to not meet Gandalf in Valinor.  I don't think Elrond was ever there, but she certainly was.

Comment: @WadCheber Elrond was not; he was born in Middle-earth late in the First Age. But there is an answer for Galadriel, obliquely, from *Valquenta*: "But of Olórin that tale does not speak; for though he loved the Elves, he walked among them unseen, or in form as one of them, and they did not know whence came the fair visions or the promptings of wisdom that he put into their hearts."

Comment: @WadCheber the silmarillion states how Olòrin gave advice to people but they didn't know where it came from. Sort of whispering it in their ears while invisible I guess

Comment: Invisible Ian McKellen whispering in your ear while sleeping. Awesome with a touch of creepy.

Comment: We have a slight clue to how the elves see Gandalf in what they call him, *Mithrandir*, which IIRC means "grey pilgrim". "Grey" could indicate his robes, his hair, and/or his age, but I'm pretty sure the *Mith-* from *Mithrandir* is the same as the first syllable of *mithril*, so it might connote veneration and value. "Pilgrim" means "wanderer", "newcomer" and also "one on a sacred or spiritual journey". So the elves might see Gandalf as all of those things, and some more than others depending on the situation: "Old stranger" or "Venerable truth-seeker".

Comment: @ToddWilcox From *Unfinished Tales*: "the last-comer was named among the Elves Mithrandir, the Grey Pilgrim, for he dwelt in no place, and gathered to himself neither wealth nor followers, but ever went to and fro in the Westlands from Gondor to Angmar, and from Lindon to Lórien, befriending all folk in times of need." Interesting idea, but unfortunately doesn't tell us a whole lot; *mith-*. in particular, only means "grey" (per *Silmarillion* Appendix); there's no especial connotation of value

Comment: @JasonBaker Granted, it's entirely speculation. That said, consider the difference in English between describing someone as "grey-haired" versus "silver-haired" versus "platinum-haired". Perhaps there is only one word or syllable in Elvish that means "grey", but it's possible they are calling Gandalf "mithril-colored". I agree it doesn't tell us much. At the same time it's likely that like most of the other names Tolkein used, there are subtle layers of meaning here.

Comment: @JasonBaker , As fot yout 1st point: 
I find it highly unlikely that the Elves, and Galadriel in particular, didn't know Gandalf was "one of their Angelic spirits", since:  
a - There aren't really many options when pondering about the origins of a good-natured centuries-old humanoid (and these characteristics were known to them, since Gandalf walked among them for hundreds of years).  
b - Galadriel lived in Aman for centuries. In those times, interaction between Elves and Maiar was common. Again - unlikely for her not to recognize one of them.

Comment: @Fingolfin: I think it's entirely possible that she recognized that he must be from the West, but chose to act as though she hadn't — because if he'd wanted his origins known, he would have said something about them. I guess this is kind of far afield from the original question...

Answer (score 4):

Could it be because Galadriel and Elrond are fellow ringbearers ?

[LotR Wiki: Keepers of the Three Rings](https://lotr.fandom.com/wiki/Keepers_of_the_Rings)

Comment: Somewhat fair but marred by *"Vilya was the mightiest of these three bands"* which is the ring kept by Elrond, and not by Galadriel. So the reverence given should be to Elrond if the rings power is considered alone.

Answer (score 4):

It can be explained with some common sense and basic diplomacy: Galadriel and Elrond are Kings and they (and their subdits) are used to that reverence. They are also powerful allies (both as ring bearers and rulers of their Kingdom).

Apart than it would be out of character for Gandalf (who prefers not to act directly as long as he can avoid it) to break protocol just to brag about how powerful he is, the only possible benefit of such an action would be aleniating his allies. Even if Elrond or Galadriel put up with him, their subjects probably would not understand that they allow such a behavior in a foreign "newcomer". Not what any sensible character would do, and much less a nice one.

Note that Gandalf also shows respect to the human kings, and while he may disagree with some of their decisions, he avoids disobeying them (the only exception I recall was with Denethor's demise). Even when Gandalf disagrees with Denethor's orders to send Faramir against Osgiliath, he does nothing to prevent that.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to their wisdom, leadership and historical roles, both Galadriel and Elrond have deep historical significance.

Galadriel was born in Valinor, and remembers all the Ages of the world since the light of the Two Trees. In addition, she is described as having among the mightiest spirits among the Elves... on the same order as Fëanor (he who made the Silmarils and captured the light of the Two Trees). Finally, as other answers have noted, she bears one of the three Elven rings. So if Elves are worth revering, she is basically more worthy of reverence than almost any elf in the history of Middle-earth.

Elrond is a survivor of the tragedy of the Noldor and of Beleriand at the end of the First Age, and is among the first beings descended from Elves, Men and Melian the Maia. He is descended from Huor and from Beren on the human side, and from Indis, Olwë, Thingol and Finwë on the elven side. So in Elrond lives the legacy of the best of Elves and Men, and there's that whole angelic/demigod Maia thing. Finally, Elrond too, is one of the elven ring bearers.

Comment: Thank you @DavidW !